# What's with the passing of the jewelry?

Tags: the-godfather-3

In the meeting of the Dons in Atlantic City, moments before the helicopter attack, the dons are passing around a platter with rings, watches, necklaces etc, from which some of them take from the platter. Are the dons taking back jewelry that belongs to them and if so, why is it on the platter to start with?

Answer (score 1):

> Are the dons taking back jewelry that belongs to them and if so, why is it on the platter to start with?

### No.

The platter of jewelry  is intended to be little gifts for the Dons to choose from  as they desire.

Essentially, party favors, just really expensive ones.

Comment: @Paulie_D- OK, so who originally brought the party favors to the meeting?